# c# string analysis

Tags: c#, .net, programming-languages

I have a string for example like " :)text :)text:) :-) word :-( " i need append it in textbox(or somewhere else), with condition:

Instead of ':)' ,':-(', etc. need to call function which enter specific symbol

I thinck exists solution with Finite-state machine, but how implement it don't know. Waiting for advises.

**update:**  " :)text :)text:) :-) word :-( "  **=>**  when we meet ':)' wec all functions Smile(":)") and it display image on the textbox

**update:** i like idea with delegates and Regex.Replace. Can i when meet ':)' send to the delegate parameter ':)' and when meet ':(' other parameter.

**update:** Found solution with converting to char and comparing every symbol to ':)' if is equal call smile(':)')

Comment: You want to call for example Smiley() method where ever is ":)" in the string? Like this: `textString.Replace(":)", Smiley());` ?

Comment: Does String.Replace not fit the bill?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) with delegate where you can process matched input or you can simply use `string.Replace` method.

**Updated**:

you can do something like this:

```
        string text = "aaa :) bbb :( ccc";

        string replaced = Regex.Replace(text, @":\)|:\(", match => match.Value == ":)" ? "case1" : "case2");
```

`replaced` variable will have "aaa case1 bbb case2 ccc" value after execution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to replace portions of the string with those symbols, right? No need to build that yourself, just use [`string.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx). Something like this:

```
string text = " :)text :)text:) :-) word :-( ";
text = text.Replace(":)", "☺").Replace(":(", "☹"); // similar for others
textbox.Text += text;
```

Note that this is not the most efficient code ever produced, but if this is for something like a chat program, you'll probably never know the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a dictionary with these specific characters as the key and pull the value.